# PostGIS cut polygon by line from street side

Tags: postgis, buffer

I have this Polygon
[image]

and this Lines from the streets of Germany.
[image]

I tried many hours with ST_Split or ST_Difference to cut the polygons by the street lines but it wasnt possible.
My intention is to remove the part of the polygon which above the line.

For example like this
[image]

I painted it. So sorry for the bad quality. I hope you understand what I want to do. I just want to get the lower part from the polygon, like not above the street line. or street side.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Your first picture seems to show *multiple* polygons, and the Question does not contain any of your attempted SQL, making it difficult to help. Please [Edit] the Question to contain the SQL which came closest to achieving your goal.

Comment: Please add your SQL code.